# Cannot position properly an image when I create a responsive header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Well I am new with this, so I have this url https://bestfamily.gr and I tried to create a responsive header with image. I did the following with css

```
background: #000000 url(my_image_url) 100% 25% no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: cover;
```

The image displays a family, so when I zoom in or zoom out the image performs responsively.

But while I zoom out the image shrinks towards top and the faces in the image are not visible

Can I make the image to be shown normal and not actually hidden

Comment: There's no `background-size: cover` on the header element in the link you provided. Add that at it won't shring towards the top corner.

Comment: Yes I havent saved the above to the link I tried it with google inspect tool

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-size:cover` and then remove the `padding:153px` on `div id="page"`. It will resize responsively.